# Validating EditText values crashes app

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a EditText (inputValue) that accepts numberDecimal format, which I need to validate. The validation function is called by:

```
      buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener {
          pickFunction()    }
```

If this EditText is left blank I get an immediate program crash after each button click. If I fill in the form with a zero, then click the button, validation works as expected.

```
  fun pickFunction() {



        val s: String = inputValue.getText().toString().trim()

        val d =  inputValue.getText().toString().toDouble()

          if(s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Blank value entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          return
        }


         if( d <= 0)
         {
             Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Zero value entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
         }

  // go do something with valid value

 }
```

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button clicks giving you crash because your `Edittext` doesnt have any value and you call `.trim()`and `.toDouble()` on null object reference. Please check null check condition before calling trim and todouble methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use [toDoubleOrNull()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) instead of `toDouble()` or wrap that line in a `try-catch` to handle `NumberFormatException`.